# Create executable OSX file on Windows for .jar file

Tags: java, windows, macos, jar, executable

I have created a java program (in Eclipse). I have successfully compiled it to a **.jar** file which I can run on windows without any problems. I want to give this program to a friend who has a MacOSX. So my aim is to:

- Create a file which can be run on MacOSX

The twist is that I have to **configure it on my Windows computer** since I don't have access to a Mac. Any advice would be of great help!

Comment: I've tried this one (jar2app): https://github.com/Jorl17/jar2app but I can't install it properly.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are referring as "create a file which can be run on macOSX"

If you want to run on any OS you just need a JRE on that particular system without it you cant run. It will provide a runtime environment to run a jar file. Then use below command to run the jar.

```
java -jar Myjar_file.jar
```

Comment: Works fine on Windows but when my friend tried it it says that it cannot find the Main Class which is weird. And yes, we run on the same .jar file.

Comment: In that case check whether he has a valid jre installed in his machine. If not install a jre of same compiled or above version. if you need to try and debug it you can install a virtual machine and setup the macos and try there. follow https://www.howtogeek.com/289594/how-to-install-macos-sierra-in-virtualbox-on-windows-10/